# Refresh of an icon with the on-tap event

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to adapt the Polymer tutorial and I's having trouble with the refresh of an element.

In my polymer-element, I declare the favorite boolean to check if I click on the icon :

```
<script>
  Polymer({
  publish: {
    favorite: {
      value: false,
      reflect: true
    }
  },
  loveTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
    alert('loveTapped');
    this.favorite = !this.favorite;
    this.refresh;
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is the code of my icon :

```
<core-icon-button
  id="icon_love"
  icon="favorite"
  on-tap="{{loveTapped}}">
</core-icon-button>
```

And in my style, i fill the icon if the value of "favorite" is true :

```
:host([favorite]) #icon_love {
  fill: #da4336;
}
```

I've check that I fire the event (with my alert('loveTapped');) and that's the case but the icon didn't refresh. I try to add a "this.refresh;" but without success

Do someone know why the icon didn't refresh and what I can do about it ?

Thanks in advance,

Edit : Seems my problem was the core-icon-button can't handle the fill attribute. But core-icon can so I just change my core-icon-button in a core-icon and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS `color` property instead of `fill`:

```
:host([favorite]) #icon_love {
  color: #da4336;
}
```

Here's a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pinitiko/1/edit?html,css,output).

**Why does this work?**

`core-icon` applies the CSS `fill: currentColor;` to itself. This sets the SVG `fill` to the value of the CSS `color` property. Since `color` cascades through Shadow DOM, applying it to the outer `core-icon-button` is sufficient.

Comment: Excellent, it's the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
  publish: {
    favorite: {
      value: false,
      reflect: true
    }
  },
  loveTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
    alert('loveTapped');
    this.favorite = !this.favorite;
    this.refresh();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work however. I've got the error  : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " I think that my "this" is not working. Perhaps is there an other way to force the refresh than this.refresh ? Or something prevent the automatic refresh (it is suppose to refresh without this ordre I think)

Comment: can you output the value of this.refresh in the console?

Comment: I tried Console.log(this.refresh()); but the error fire first. Here's the complete error : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function tache-card5.html:71
Polymer.loveTapped tache-card5.html:71
d.dispatchMethod events.js:41
(anonymous function) events.js:73
e.up tap.js:85
h.gestureTrigger dispatcher.js:290"

Comment: just this : Console.log(this.refresh);

Comment: I obtain : "undefined"

Comment: ok, thats what I thought, you need to declare this function before you try call it.

Comment: Ok, I change my css for the icon to make the position change if the event fire and that's the case. It's not a problem of refresh then but just that I've got trouble with the fill instruction. Thanks for your answers